# For which $\alpha$, the function series $u_{n}(x)=n^{\alpha} \cdot x^{n} \cdot(1-x)$ uniformly converges on $[0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If $\alpha \geqslant 1$, the sequence $(m_{n})_{n \geqslant 1}$ defined by
$$m_{n}=\sup _{x\in[0 ; 1]}|U_{n}(x)|=\left|u_{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right|=\frac{n \alpha}{n+1} \cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$
diverges: $(u_{n})_{n\geqslant 1}$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$. Thus,$\sum_{n \geqslant 1} u_{n}$ has not uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ for $\alpha \geqslant 1$. If $\alpha<0$, $\sum_{n \geq 1} u_{n}$ normally converges on $[0,1]$. Thus $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} u_{n}$ uniformly converges on $[0,1]$.

Let $0 \leqslant \alpha<1$. We introduce the sequence $(R_{n})_{n\geqslant 1}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
R_{n}:[0, 1] & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ x & \longmapsto R_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k^{\alpha} \cdot x^{k} \cdot(1-x) \end{align*}

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$,
\begin{align*}
k \geqslant n+1 & \Rightarrow k^{\alpha} \geqslant(n+1)^{\alpha}\\
& \Rightarrow k^{\alpha} \cdot x^{k} \cdot(1-x) \geqslant(n+1)^{\alpha} \cdot x^{k}(1-x)\\
& \Rightarrow R_{n}(x) \geqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}(n+1)^{\alpha} \cdot x^{k}(1-x).
\end{align*}
As $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}(n+1)^{\alpha} \cdot x^{k} \cdot(1-x)=(n+1)^{\alpha} \cdot x^{n+1}$, then for all $0<a<1$,
\begin{align*}
x \geqslant a & \Rightarrow R_{n}(x) \geqslant(n+1)^{\alpha} \cdot a^{n+1}\\
& \Rightarrow R_{n}(x) \geqslant a^{n+1}>0,
\end{align*}
we deduce from this inequality that $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} u_{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $[a,1]$.

Now for $x\in[0,a)$, I don't really see how to solve the problem. Is it really necessary to study this case or we could just try to see what happens when $x=0$?

Comment: Your argument for $x \in [a,1)$ is incorrect because $a^{n+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ when $a < 1$.

Comment: @RRL i think i have it now. I get inspired from your answer. Before the penultimate inequality of my proof if we take the supremum we will find that sup(Rn(x))>(n+1)^alpha >1 as sup(x^(n+1))=1 for x in [0,1]. Thanks a lot for your clarification!

Comment: I think convergence is not uniform on$ [1,1]$ and uniform on $[0,a]$.

Comment: For $x \in [0,a]$ with $a < 1$ and $0 \leqslant \alpha < 1$  the term is dominated by $na^n$ and the series is uniformly convergent by the Weierstrass test since $\sum n a^n$ converges.

Comment: You just need a different argument for $[a,1]$ as I show below.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $0 \leqslant \alpha < 1$ and $x \in [a,1]$ with $0< a < 1$.  We have

$$\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty k^\alpha x^k(1-x)\right| \geqslant n^\alpha (1-x) \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x^k = n^\alpha x^{n+1},$$

and with $x_n = 1 - 1/n \in [a,1]$ for all sufficiently large $n$,

$$\sup_{x \in [a,1]}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty k^\alpha x^k(1-x)\right| > n^\alpha (1-1/n)^{n+1} \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow \begin{cases}\infty, & 0 < \alpha < 1\\ e^{-1}, &\alpha = 0 \end{cases}$$

Hence, the convergence is not uniform on $[a,1]$.

---

Alternatively,

$$\sum_{k=n+1} ^{2n} k^\alpha x^k (1-x) \geqslant n \cdot n^\alpha\cdot x^{2n}\cdot (1-x),$$

and with $x_n = 1 - 1/n$ we have

$$\sup_{x \in [a,1]}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty k^\alpha x^k(1-x)\right| \geqslant \sup_{x \in [a,1]}\sum_{k=n+1} ^{2n} k^\alpha x^k (1-x)> n\cdot n^\alpha \cdot (1- 1/n)^{2n}\cdot (1 - (1-1/n)) \\=n^\alpha (1-1/n)^{2n} \underset{n \to \infty}{\not\to}  0$$

Comment: Your proof is still true for $x\in[a,1]$ it seems?

Comment: Revised.  The first proof was incorrect.

Comment: This still does not seem right. You are missing a factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ in the middle side of your bottom inequality with $x_n =1-\frac{1}{n}$ ; this goes to $0$ for $\alpha <1$ and goes to $\infty$ for $\alpha >1$.

Comment: @Mike:  Can you show me what "middle side" is?

Comment: Are you asking what happened to $(1-x)$?

Comment: $(1-x)\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x^k  = x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes what happened to $(1-x_n)=\frac{1}{n}$, please

Comment: But, $1-x_n$ goes to $0$. How do you have $1-x_n =x_n^{n+1}$, which is lower-bounded by approximately $e^{-1}$?

Comment: Please look at $(1-x)\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x^k  = x^{n+1}$

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: That $\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty k^\alpha x^k(1-x)\right| \geqslant n^\alpha x^{n+1}$ was already worked out correctly by the OP.  The $(1-x)$ is canceled.

Comment: @RRL Good answer!